# creating nested array presto

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

But I have this table:

```sql
with cte (customer_id, product, sell) as (
  values 
  (1, 'a', 100), 
  (1, 'b', 150),
  (2, 'a', 90),
  (2, 'b', 110)
)

select * from cte
```

**I want a result like the following**:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| result                                                   |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
| {1: {"a": 100, "b": 150}, 2: {"a":90, "b": 110}}         |
+----------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: And what is actual output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your result is not a nested array but a nested map. I would say that unless this is part of some bigger query it is quite strange to try mapping whole table to a single row especially taking in account size of data usually handled by Athena but for this test data you can use `map_agg` and nested grouping:

```sql
with cte (customer_id, product, sell) as (
    values (1, 'a', 100),
        (1, 'b', 150),
        (2, 'a', 90),
        (2, 'b', 110)
)

select map_agg(customer_id, m) as result                                                   
from (
        select customer_id, map_agg(product, sell) m
        from cte
        group by customer_id
    )
group by true -- fake grouping
```

Output:

| result |
| --- |
| {1={a=100, b=150}, 2={a=90, b=110}} |